# Search function with 2 JComboBox - searching with 1st the 2nd is not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, event-dispatch-thread

It runs fine but when choosing the  `idCombo` with which I'm searching, the `nameFIeld` which is also a `JComboBox` does not change but remains the first in the list, while all other fields change accord.

```
package GUI;

import Logic.*; //Inherits from vector class found in the package Logic
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; //Works with the ActionListener

    public class Search extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

        //Panels
        private JPanel north = new JPanel(); 
        private JPanel south = new JPanel();
        private JPanel west = new JPanel();
        private JPanel east = new JPanel();
        private JPanel center = new JPanel();

        //Labels
        private JLabel mainTitle = new JLabel ("Search Records"); //Main title

        private JLabel westLabel = new JLabel ("      "); //To create margins
        private JLabel eastLabel = new JLabel ("      ");

        //Labels and Text Fields 

        private JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("CD ID");
        private JComboBox idCombo = new JComboBox(); 
        //To create a drop down list of CD IDs

        private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Customer Name");  
        private JComboBox nameField;

        private JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Date");
        private JTextField dateField = new JTextField();

        private JLabel subjectLabel = new JLabel("Subject");
        private JTextField subjectField = new JTextField();

        private JLabel fileLabel = new JLabel("File");
        private JTextField fileField = new JTextField();

        private JLabel pageLabel = new JLabel("Page"); 
        private JTextField pageField = new JTextField();

        //Buttons 
        private JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        //Creating an instance of type VectorRecord 
        private VectorRecord vr;
        private VectorCustomer vc;

            public Search(VectorRecord vr, VectorCustomer vc){

                //NORTH PANEL 
                super("Search Records");

                this.vr = vr;
                this.vc = vc;


                this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //Setting the 'Search Records' window layout to Border Layout
                this.add(north,BorderLayout.NORTH); //Adding the north panel to the Border Layout 
                mainTitle.setFont(new Font ("Arial",Font.BOLD,20)); //Arranging the font of the main title
                mainTitle.setForeground(Color.black); //Arranging the color of the main title
                north.add(mainTitle); // Adding the maintitle to the north panel


                //CENTER PANEL                 
                center.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2,0,15)); //6 rows, 2 columns and spacing
                this.add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER); //Adding the center panel to the Border Layout

                //Adding Labels and TextFields to the center panel
                center.add(idLabel);
                center.add(idCombo);
                idCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(vr.fillIdCombo())); //fillIdCombo is a method  in VectorRecords class
                idCombo.addActionListener(this);
                idLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size 

                center.add(nameLabel);
                center.add(nameField);
                nameField.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(vc.fillCustomerCombo()));
                nameField.addActionListener(this);
                nameLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size 


                center.add(dateLabel); 
                center.add(dateField);
                dateLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size 

                center.add(subjectLabel); 
                center.add(subjectField);
                subjectLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size 

                center.add(fileLabel); 
                center.add(fileField);
                fileLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size 


                center.add(pageLabel);
                center.add(pageField);
                pageLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16)); //Arranging the font and size        


                //WEST & EAST PANEL 
                //To create margins
                west.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Setting the west panel in the border layout, to Flow layout 
                this.add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);
                west.add(westLabel);
                east.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Setting the east panel in the border layout, to Flow layout
                this.add(east,BorderLayout.EAST);
                east.add(eastLabel);

                //SOUTH PANEL
                south.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Setting the south panel in the border layout, to Flow layout
                this.add(south,BorderLayout.SOUTH); //Adding the south panel to the BorderLayout
                south.add(exitButton); //Adding the Exit button to the south panel
                exitButton.addActionListener(this); //In order for the Exit button to work


                this.setSize(450,350); //Giving the window a size and location a
                this.setLocation(320,250);
                this.setVisible(true);
            }

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
                Record tempRecord= new Record();
                Record modifiedRecord = new Record();
                String recordId = (String)idCombo.getSelectedItem();
                tempRecord = vr.getRecordRec(Integer.parseInt(recordId));


                    if(event.getSource() instanceof JComboBox){
                        if(event.getSource() == idCombo){


                            nameField.setSelectedItem((Customer) tempRecord.getCustomer());
                            dateField.setText(tempRecord.getDate());
                            subjectField.setText(tempRecord.getSubject());
                            fileField.setText(tempRecord.getFile());
                            pageField.setText(tempRecord.getPage() + "");

                        }
                    }

                    if(event.getSource().equals(exitButton)){
                            vr.saveRecordsToFile();
                            this.dispose();                                                        
                        }


                    }


                }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke **setSelectedItem** on nameField with the **Customer** object returned by **tempRecord.getCustomer()** it will try to find the whether the object is already present in the nameField combobox.

While checking it will invoke equals method for object equality, make sure you override equals method of the **Customer** class.